# Keep the data save in sharedPreference although pressed back button - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have some problem as I mention in my question. I have two activity, Activity A and Activity B. When I Enter some data in Activity A, then I press next button, it will redirect to Activity B. At Activity B, I also enter some data. When I press back button, the data at Activity A is display as I entered before. When I press next button, the data that I entered at Activity B is missing. Below is my `SharedPreferences` code.

**Activity A:**

public class NewSuggestion extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText etYear, etMonth, etTitle, etOwnValue;
private RadioGroup rgSuggestWill;
private RadioButton radioButton;
private Button btnNext;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
private Spinner spReviewer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_suggestion);

    final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();
    View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_new_suggestion, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView tvTitle = viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvTitle.setText("NEW SUGGESTION");
    abar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
    abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    etTitle = findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    etYear = findViewById(R.id.etYear);
    etMonth = findViewById(R.id.etMonth);
    rgSuggestWill =findViewById(R.id.rgSuggestWill);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String mm = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.US);
    int yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    etYear.setText(new StringBuilder().append(yy));
    etMonth.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mm));

    spReviewer = findViewById(R.id.spReviewer);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.reviewer,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spReviewer.setAdapter(adapter);
    spReviewer.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("title",etTitle.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("year",etYear.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("month",etMonth.getText().toString());

            // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = rgSuggestWill.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioButton = findViewById(selectedId);
            editor.putString("suggestionwill",radioButton.getText().toString());
            if (spReviewer.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Please choose")){

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewSuggestion.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Please choose your reviewer");
                alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }else{
                editor.putString("reviewer",spReviewer.getSelectedItem().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(NewSuggestion.this,NewSuggestion2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            editor.apply();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewSuggestion.this, DashboardApp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

**Activity B:**

```
public class NewSuggestion2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText etPresent, etDetails, etBenefit;
private ImageView imgAttach,btnCamera,btnGallery;
private Button btnNext,btnClear;
private Intent intent;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
public  static final int RequestPermissionCode  = 1 ;

public static final String DEFAULT = "N/A";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_suggestion2);

    final ActionBar abar = getSupportActionBar();
    View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_new_suggestion, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    TextView tvTitle = viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.title);
    tvTitle.setText("NEW SUGGESTION (Cont..)");
    abar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
    abar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    abar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //abar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    abar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    etPresent = findViewById(R.id.etPresent);
    etDetails = findViewById(R.id.etDetails);
    etBenefit = findViewById(R.id.etBenefit);

    imgAttach = findViewById(R.id.imgAttach);

    btnCamera=findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
    EnableRuntimePermission();
    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
        }
    });
    btnGallery=findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);
    btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Photo"),REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
    btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                editor.putString("present", etPresent.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("details", etDetails.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("benefit", etBenefit.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();


            Intent intent = new Intent(NewSuggestion2.this,ConfirmSuggestion.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnClear = findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
    btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imgAttach.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    });

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 7 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        imgAttach.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){

        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try{
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imgAttach.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void EnableRuntimePermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(NewSuggestion2.this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA))
    {

        Toast.makeText(NewSuggestion2.this,"CAMERA permission allows us to Access CAMERA app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(NewSuggestion2.this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode);

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int RC, String per[], int[] PResult) {

    switch (RC) {

        case RequestPermissionCode:

            if (PResult.length > 0 && PResult[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Toast.makeText(NewSuggestion2.this,"Permission Granted, Now your application can access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(NewSuggestion2.this,"Permission Canceled, Now your application cannot access CAMERA.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


}
```

}

Comment: check your shared preferences save data or not in device file explorer.

Comment: you are saving data to shared perference on btnNext click but you never clicked next in ActivityB. Try saving data to shared preference on TextChangedListener or save data in Next and backpress both

Comment: in your Activity B, call the data storing for shared prefs also in the OnBackPressed method

Comment: you can follow this answer to save and retrieve your data in sahredPreference :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792257/how-to-control-storing-user-data-using-sharedpreferences-when-logging-in-and-out/55792301#55792301 follow this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign value to present,details,benefit from sharedpref

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

 etPresent = findViewById(R.id.etPresent);
    etDetails = findViewById(R.id.etDetails);
    etBenefit = findViewById(R.id.etBenefit);

etPresent.setText(sharedPref.getString("present", ""));
etDetails.setText(sharedPref.getString("details", ""));
etBenefit.setText(sharedPref.getString("benefit", ""));
```

In Activity B make sure you save data in `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    editor.putString("present", etPresent.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("details", etDetails.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("benefit", etBenefit.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();     
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: when I do this. the problem still occurs. should I remove the sharedPreference in next button?

Comment: Not necessary , When you open activity B make sure you are setting values(present,present,present). from sahredpref. According to my knowledge you are able to store data's in shared preference but not using it properly. can you share entire code of activity A and B?

Comment: Let me clear about life cycle of this two activities. 1.You create activity A. 2.Enter some values 3.press next and  activity B will be created. 4.When you press back in activity B same instance of activity A will be shown.  but when you press next again New instance of activity B will be created(so wit wont be having entered data's)

Comment: Better if you update your question itself with code.

Comment: Updated answer as well.

Comment: 'Assign vale to present,details,benefit from sharedpref' -  this code is put at Activity A?

Comment: Activity B only.

Comment: in button next? or else?

Comment: You are creating sharedpref inside a buttonnext pressed , instead of this create it in onCreate(). Add this lines `etPresent.setText(sharedPref.getString("present", ""));
etDetails.setText(sharedPref.getString("details", ""));
etBenefit.setText(sharedPref.getString("benefit", ""));` After `etPresent = findViewById(R.id.etPresent);
    etDetails = findViewById(R.id.etDetails);
    etBenefit = findViewById(R.id.etBenefit);`

Comment: Thanks, its work !! but how about spinner and radio button? cannot use 'setText'

Comment: For that you have to save some value when you select a spinner / button. Based on this value you have to set default spinner value/button later(when you open Activity B again). as this is totally different question we cannot discuss here. Please accept my answer if it helped , thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the onBackPress() method.In Activity B it is necessary to put data in to SharedPreferences.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("MyData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("present", etPresent.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("details", etDetails.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("benefit", etBenefit.getText().toString());    
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: when I do this. the problem still occurs. should I remove the sharedPreference in next button?